# Incomplete Landscape Transitions in UINavigationControllers in iOS7

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I am experiencing what I believe is a bug in iOS7 with landscape transitions in a UINavigationController.

I am manually loading up the root view controller into the navigation controller and then pushing the next VC's from code onto the stack. When I do so, I am getting incomplete transitions as shown in [This Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApJdjcqIm94&feature=em-upload_owner)

Is anyone else experiencing this issue with landscape transitions on UINavigationControllers on iOS7? This code works flawlessly on iOS6...

Comment: The same is happening for me. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It appeared because you are doing some calculation or performing some operations either in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Comment: I am not. And, which vc's view life cycle callbacks are you referring to? The navigaiton controller's or the presented controller's?

Comment: The one you are using for transitioning to next view controller. Can you post some of your code here?